# FullCalendar only showing 1 google calendar event in the top left box

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am having trouble connecting Google calendar to Full Calendar.  The event only shows up in the top left calendar frame. If I enter multiple events in the google calendar, it only displays one in the top left frame as well. Code posted below.

```
<link href="../css/main_text.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/info%4011floor.com/public/basic',
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/New_York' // an option!
    }
  });
});

</script>

<link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```